# how to Create .deb package while installation ask for configurations?

Tags: ubuntu, package, debian, deb

I want to create .deb package that show dialog to get configuration while installation.
I have simple C++ exe file.I want to make it a deb package but i want to ask some configurations while installation with dpkg command.
I use dpkg-buildpackage but it dose not help.
Would you please help me out.

Comment: what configurations do you want to ask? please add some more info.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by using preinst,prerm, postinst and postrm files into debian folder which make by debmake command. Those files can hold scripts that run before and after installation and remove package